# Creating and plotting an array as a function of values in another array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, plot, statistics

I'm quite a programming noob and I've only been using Python more intensively for a few weeks, however, I currently need it for an application in statistics, I am trying to do the following:

Create an array of integers *N* from 1 up to *Q=A q* (so *N=[1,2,...,Q-1,Q]*), and use this to create and plot an array with values for the function [*P(N)*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGgg3.png) which sums over binomial coefficients. *A* and *q* are integer constants (*N>q* is in there as a true/false statement on purpose). I currently have the following code:

```
#Constants {A,Q,S,sigma} are set
q=Q/A
n = np.linspace(1,Q,Q,dtype=int) #variable array
Sum = np.zeros((1,Q)) 
Iteration = np.zeros((1,Q))

alpha = 0
while alpha < A:
    alpha=alpha+1

    Iteration = sigma^alpha * (comb(n-1,alpha-1) -(n>q)*alpha*comb( max(0,n-q-1), alpha-1) )     
    Sum = Sum + Iteration
```

This returns a typeError "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index" in the line "Iteration=..." (and probably in the next line as well), and I can't find out what exactly the problem is and how to fix this.

Also; I might be doing the summation in a convoluted way; if there is a better way to sum over this in python, help to that end are also welcome.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the following line:

```
Iteration = sigma^alpha * (comb(n-1,alpha-1) -(n>q)*alpha*comb( max(0,n-q-1), alpha-1) )
```

As the parameters for comb has to be two non negative integers, see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-math-comb-method/), when you pass in n, which is an ndarray, to comb it will return the TypeError you mentioned.

Potentially you could wrap around the while loop and make it a function? Then you can iterate it and append the result to a list.

```
def this_fun(n):
Sum = 0
Q = 1000
A = 100
sigma = 1
q = int(Q / A)
alpha = 0
while alpha < A:
    alpha = alpha+1
    Iteration = sigma^alpha * (comb(n-1,alpha-1) -(n>q)*alpha*comb( max(0,n-q-1), alpha-1) )
    Sum += Iteration
return Sum

P_N=[]
N = 100
for i in range(1,N):
    P_N.append(this_fun(i))
```

You have to double check the logic on the Iteration line to make sure you are implementing what the maths notication is intended to and put in some sensible value for Q, A and N.

The function looks as if I plot P_N against N, is it what you are expecting?
[image]

Comment: Alright, thanks, makes sense; that also explains why it does work for any functions that don't use the comb() function. Could you maybe suggest a good method to apply the function to every element of the array n, and output those results in a similar array?

Comment: Let me modifiy the answer above and give you an example.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! I ended up finding out a different way to do it myself, but I'll keep your version in in order to learn. Thanks!!